# prime-select nvidia not reflected in "about" Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics, nvidia-optimus

I have a Dell XPS 15 9570 with both intel graphics and nvidia grpahics. Currently I am running Wayland (to avoid screen tearing issues) and the nvidia 410 driver.

I want to always know whether I am using intel or nvidia and be able to switch between the two.

If I run the commands

```
 sudo prime-select nvidia
 prime-select query
```

the terminal returns in fact

```
 nvidia
```

However when I go to "About", under graphics it continues to list "Intel HD Graphics (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)".

What gives?

Update: I suspect the issue is that "About" is not reflecting correctly what my computer is using. The reason being that if

```
 prime-select query
```

returns

```
 nvidia
```

Then I cannot even log into Ubuntu Xorg (Gnome crashes immediately and returns me to login screen), but if it returns

```
 intel
```

then I have no problem (FYI Wayland allows me to log on regardless). So *something* must be changing...

Comment: When you log into wayland you are using the Intel gpu even if the nvidia drivers are installed. There is no wayland support for nvidia drivers in  'optimus' laptops and likely never will be.

Comment: To clarify above - Even if nvidia drivers are installed & **selected** a wayland session will switch to Intel. If you were able to log into an Xserver session you'd be using the NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: What about if I use the Nouveau display driver? Wayland still will use Intel?

Comment: I've no clue myself how you'd do that on an optimus laptop. Here I've no issue, nvidia driver is installed and prime-selected. On X session it's nvidia, on wayland it's intel

Answer (score 0):

you need to reboot after running

> `prime-select` (nvidia or intel)

for the changes to take effect,

also `ligtDM` (Display manager) with `Unity 7` (now community maintained) desktop (deptecated by Canonical since Ubuntu 16.04) seems to work better, for nVidia with multiple GPU setup,

than `GDM` (Display Manager) which is the default for `Gnome Desktop` which is the default Desktop Environment since `Ubuntu 18.04` (I think).

Comment: This is true but actually not my problem,which I think is fully addressed in the comments above. Thanks though